# Sendinblue PHP API - multiple recipients only sends to last in array

Tags: php, sendinblue

I am trying to send emails to multiple recipients using SendinBlue's API v3 Php Library (https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-php-library).

The following code, I think, it set up correctly - in that the code goes down printing the `$result` part of the code, meaning there was no exception.

However, when testing sending to multiple recipients, only the email address that's the last one in the array (person2@exampe.com in the code below) receives the email.

If I flip the `to` array contents around, so that `person1@example.com` appears last in the array, then only that address receives the email.

This is the sample code:

```
// ####################################################
// Sendinblue Email
// ####################################################

$config = SendinBlue\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('api-key', $send_in_blue_api_key);

$apiInstance = new SendinBlue\Client\Api\TransactionalEmailsApi(
    new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
    $config
);
$sendSmtpEmail = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\SendSmtpEmail();
$sendSmtpEmail['subject'] = 'Mulitple Recipients Email Test';
$sendSmtpEmail['htmlContent'] = $html;
$sendSmtpEmail['sender'] = array('name' => 'Test Messages', 'email' => 'messages@example.com');
$sendSmtpEmail['to'] = array(
    array('email' => 'person1@example.com', 'name' => 'Bugs Bunny'
        , 'email' => 'person2@example.com', 'name' => 'Daffy Duck')
);
$sendSmtpEmail['replyTo'] = array('email' => 'sender@example.com', 'name' => 'Reply Name');
try {
    $result = $apiInstance->sendTransacEmail($sendSmtpEmail);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $send_error = $e->getMessage();
    print_r($send_error);
}
```

I tried changing the `to` array from:

```
$sendSmtpEmail['to'] = array(
    array('email' => 'person1@example.com', 'name' => 'Bugs Bunny'
        , 'email' => 'person2@example.com', 'name' => 'Daffy Duck')
);
```

To:

```
$sendSmtpEmail['to'] = array('email' => 'person1@example.com', 'name' => 'Bugs Bunny'
                           , 'email' => 'person2@example.com', 'name' => 'Daffy Duck');
```

But, the API returns this, which I think means the way I'm defining the multiple recipients in the `to` array is correct:

```
[400] Client error: `POST https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"code":"invalid_parameter","message":"to is not valid"}
```

I wondered if there is any way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make an array of arrays. Each array should have `email` and  `name` key:

Short array syntax:

```
$sendSmtpEmail['to'] = [
    ['email' => 'person1@example.com', 'name' => 'Bugs Bunny'],
    ['email' => 'person2@example.com', 'name' => 'Daffy Duck'],
];
```

Equivalent to:

```
$sendSmtpEmail['to'] = array(
    array('email' => 'person1@example.com', 'name' => 'Bugs Bunny'),
    array('email' => 'person2@example.com', 'name' => 'Daffy Duck'),
);
```